# Question on toilet mounting; No visible bolts?

Tags: plumbing, toilet, old-house

OK,In the early 80-81, My Aunt allowed her Husband to build in a dead Attic space over the Foyer that has 15-17 ft ceiling, a rather sizable Laboratory(I'm not quite sure what to call it.). the floor was on 3 or 4 different levels,highest part 8-10" from the lowest part. but the built in Ventilation, shelving, Commercial stainless counters and sink made it work. So the space was anything. but an easy space to work with.

In 06-07 my Aunt had her Late Husbands Laboratory(Amateur Perfume & Healing oil Blender, Later a Black room I think as well.) converted in to a 3rd bathroom in their 100+ year old home. In 2009-2010, she had the toilet painted/colored white to match the Walk in Bath/sauna tub she had installed.

So now you know this is not a simple room.  Now the issue. the foyer has a blue water marks in the ceiling. I suspect its the toilet. But the toilet has no floor mount nuts/bolts or covers or anything.

2 different flooring guys couldn't match the non-slip semi-clear Ceramic tiles that cover the bathroom floor and stairs to it.

I talked to the people who were supposed to have recolored the toilet. but their paper work says they refused the job because the toilet was unmovable. But they may have had one of their techs do such work off the books. because there is no insurance on it since they could not dry the color properly.

So are there any Toilets that mount up through the floor? bolts Bolting in to the bottom of the toilet??

I suspect its a Toto toilet 20" Height, This is matching up the lines and curves of the bowl. But the height of her bowl is to low for the measurements of the one i suspect it is or it's mounted 4 1/2" below the tiled floor.

Or any other suggestions? IDeas?

Comment: Is there any brand/model on the toilet? Can you post a pic of it?

Comment: I'm sure this is something regional, but what is a "Mickey Mouse install"? A hack job, or something else?

Comment: Pictures would help. Easing up on the Random capitalization Might also make it more Readable. Hmm. Aunt's late husband by name of Fester, perchance?

Comment: I took pictures but they are not view able.  There is no brand I can find on it.(part of the problem).

Comment: It's been recolored/painted from pale blue to White. So it might be there under the paint somewhere.  I looked at the back of the bowl in front of the tank.  and sanded threw the ceramic color and found nothing.

Comment: Mickey Mouse work is a Hack job. I'm sorry i was typing on an 5" Old tablet with a camera on it.

Comment: Photos, please add some photos!

Comment: This could possibly be a back flushing toilet. Is it attached to the wall in any way?

Comment: This isn't an answer so it is a comment ... sometimes, in remodeling, you must destroy things first.

Comment: @  Jason Hutchinson, there is less then an inch between the wall and the toilet. Its a floor mounted toilet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many toilets are held in place around their bases with silicone sealant only these days, especially if the cistern is fastened to the wall.

No toilet I have ever seen (in 30 years in trade) is mounted directly from underneath i.e. accessed from under the floor).

Many modern toilets have a pair of plastic multiholed brackets that are screwed to the floor, the toilet drops over these and screws through the side of the pan hold it in place. Silicone sealant is still advised.

Older toilets screwed directly through the pan base into the floor.

Anyone seen anything else?

Comment: So there is a base under the flooring. That was what I was afraid of.

Comment: @gurby A photo and you'd of had this question answered in five minutes.

Comment: if the pictures had turned out viable, I'd have linked them.  but at the time the lights in the room would not go on.  but they were no help at all. I kind got the answer i suspected. the toilet was mounted below the tile floor.